# Is there any open source software similar as Instagram

Tags: software-recommendation, photo

I ask you guys if anyone knows if there is an open software, similar to [**Instagram**](http://instagr.am/) for Desktop or Phone use? I know that there is Gimp, Inkskape and others, but I want something similar to **Instagram** specifically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you want it to do? Many of us aren't familiar with instagram (and can't install to try it)

Comment: "Instagram is a fast, beautiful and fun way to share your life with friends through a series of pictures. Snap a photo with your iPhone, choose a filter to transform the look and feel, send to Facebook, Twitter or Flickr" for us who do not know about it.

Comment: I forgot, sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For phone use there is Streamzoo which has more interactive features than Instagram. In Streamzoo having your photos liked is converted to points, and you can unlock badges based on the hashtags used on your photos. It's available for iPhone and Android phones. I personally use it more than IG.

Answer (score 5):

[**Shotwell**](http://yorba.org/shotwell/). It is the default photo manager in Ubuntu 11.04.

> Through the use of plugins, Shotwell
>   can publish photos and videos to the
>   following services, each of which
>   requires an account:
>
> - Facebook
> - Flickr
> - Picasa Web Albums
> - YouTube (videos only)
> - Yandex.Fotki, a photo site popular in Russia (photos only)
> - Any site running the Piwigo photo gallery software (photos only)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I've found a nice app for making some nice vintage old style photos, as nice as Instagram...
Maybe you should check it out here:

http://vintagejs.com/

and here (you can find it on chrome web store) and it calls [Instant Retro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jlahmeejnbkdnjnckboeglpfmjbfmopp?hl=pt-PT#):

and share your photos with a nice retro style!

Answer (score 2):

There's a new project in development, funded through Kickstarter:

[The Open Photo Project](http://theopenphotoproject.org/)

It currently has a web interface, an iPhone application and offers syncing with Dropbox and Amazon S3.

[image: Screenshot of the web view]

Comment: It seems very promising...

Answer (score 2):

To simply look at your Instagram page you can use Fogger. The use of Fogger is very obvious when you launch it. Enter a name and a URL - that is it. From then on you can just click on the generated icon and up comes your Instagram page as though it were an application. Fogger can be used for other web sites too.

Another option, if you use the Chrome browser, is to go to 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home
in chrome and search for Instagram. There are several applications to chose from.

Answer (score 1):

I've started an open source iOS library for providing similar live filtering/blur effects.

You can grab the code here https://github.com/gobackspaces/DLCImagePickerController

Would love some help as there are still a few things to sort out

Answer (score 1):

xnretro it is exactly what you was looking for.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/xnretro-add-instagram-like-effects-to.html

Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

[Inkstagram](http://inkstagram.com/) .

> A site for browsing and managing photos from Instagram

Comment: can you add new photos there? (It doesn't look like you can to me)

Comment: I think we should have an apple account first...

Comment: Last I checked, there was no public API for uploading photos to Instagram.